# Why does {} == false evaluate to false while [] == false evaluates to true?

Tags: javascript, boolean, equality-operator

Why does `{} == false`   evaluate to `false` while `[] == false` evaluates to `true` in javascript?

Comment: because javascript, google "wat" + javascript (Destroy All Software Talks)

Comment: For extra sh**s and giggles : `if([])alert("wtf")`

Comment: `==` likes to compare stuff as numbers or strings, so {}==="objectObject" but []=="" as a string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the type conversion that takes place according to the [Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3):

```
{} == false                // step 7 {} == ToNumber(false)
{} == 0                    // step 9 ToPrimitve({}) == 0
"[object Object]" == 0     // step 5 ToNumber("[object Object]") == 0
NaN == 0                   // step 1.c.i

[] == false                // step 7 [] == ToNumber(false)
[] == 0                    // step 9 ToPrimitve([]) == 0
"" == 0                    // step 5 ToNumber("") == 0
0 == 0                     // step 1.c.iii
```

References: [ToNumber](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3), [ToPrimitive](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1)

And because of this, prefer to use strict comparison.

---

Some examples how `ToPrimitive` converts objects to primitives *during comparison*. By default, the `valueOf` method of the object will be called, and then `toString` if `valueOf` doesn't return a primitive value. For `Date` objects it will call `toString` by default.

```
var obj = {};
obj.valueOf();        // Object { } // the object itself
obj.toString();       // "[object Object]"


obj.valueOf = function() { return 123; };
obj == 123; // true

obj.toString = function() { return 'foo bar'; };
obj == 123; // false
obj == 'foo bar'; // true

// Date object

var date = new Date();
date.valueOf();        // 1421430720379
date.toString();       // "Fri Jan 16 2015 09:52:00 GMT-0800 (PST)"

date == 1421430720379 // false
date == "Fri Jan 16 2015 09:52:00 GMT-0800 (PST)" // true

date.toString = function() { return 'foo'; };
date == 'foo'; // true
```

Comment: Does this mean that the primitives of all objects are strings? @FelixKling Btw, thanks for such a clear answer! :)

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. ToPrimitive accepts a hint which should indicate whether the object should be converted to a number or string. If no hint is provided, the default is "string" for Date objects and "number" for all other objects. In case of "number", the `valueOf` method of that object is called. **However** if that method does *not return* a primitive value, it falls back to `toString`. And by default, `valueOf` simply returns the object itself, so it's not a primitive.

Comment: Added some examples how objects are converted to primitives.