# Handling my object's casting to number

Tags: javascript

As you all know there is a `toString()` method for object which is called whenever the casting is required.

I was wondering if there is such a method for casting to number (like the Date object in which `+new Date()` returns the `getTime()` method's value).

For example (let's say there is `toNumber` method):

```
function MyObj(){}
MyObj.prototype.toNumber = function(){
    return 1362;
}
```

Comment: Wait, `+new Date()` is magic and returns the timestamp? That's horrifying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called [**`valueOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf):

```
function MyObj(){}
MyObj.prototype.valueOf = function(){
    return 1362;
}
```

See also the second part of [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27989332/218196).

Comment: I honestly had no idea this was part of JavaScript, and I consider myself fairly well-versed in JS's oddities.